# What's the best way to handle authentication with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have a `ProtectedRoute` component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import CreateRecipe from "./components/CreateRecipe";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import UserContext from './contexts/UserContext';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';
import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage';
import EditRecipe from './components/EditRecipe';
import SearchPage from './components/SearchPage';
import ViewRecipe from './components/ViewRecipe';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


/**
 * Used for Routes that cannot be accessed without authentication
 */
function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const [authCheck, setAuthCheck] = useState({ isAuth: false, loading: true });
  const { auth } = useContext(UserContext.context);

  //async call to check authentication status
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/authUser').then(res => {
      setAuthCheck({ isAuth: res.data.isAuth, loading: false });
    });
  }, []);

  return (

    <Route {...rest} render={(props) =>
      (!authCheck.loading) ? (authCheck.isAuth || auth) ? (<Component {...props} />) : (<Redirect to={{
        pathname: "/login",
        state: { from: props.location },
      }} />)
        : (<div>loading</div>)
    } />
  );

}

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <UserContext>
          <ProtectedRoute component={Homepage} path="/:username/home" />
          <ProtectedRoute path='/:username/edit/:id' component={EditRecipe} />
          <ProtectedRoute path='/:username/create' component={CreateRecipe} />
          <ProtectedRoute path='/:username/search/:q' component={SearchPage} />
          <ProtectedRoute path='/:username/view/:id' component={ViewRecipe} />
          <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        </UserContext>
        <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I found that the useEffect hook fires before the component is even rendered. This causes `authCheck.isAuth` to be permanently be false, thus preventing the user from logging in. To get around that, I made my login component update the context's auth state.

How would I get around the useEffect issue? Also, is there a better way to set up authentication on the client side?

Comment: Actually, `useEffect` hook is fired after the component is rendered. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score -1):

Refactor the `.then()` to an `async await`. It should update the `isAuth` state correctly, and then you can remove the `auth` context.

```
const getAuthUser = async() => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/authUser');
    setAuthCheck({ isAuth: res.data.isAuth, loading: false });
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error
  } 
};

//async call to check authentication status
useEffect(() => {
  getAuthUser();
}, []);


return (

  <Route {...rest} render={(props) =>
    !authCheck.loading ? authCheck.isAuth ? (<Component {...props} />) : 
    (<Redirect to={{
      pathname: "/login",
      state: { from: props.location },
    }} />)
    : (<div>loading</div>)
   />
);
```